# Deducing lambda parameter type from input container / iterator

Tags: c++, lambda

I was wondering if/how the parameter in below lambda could be deduced from the given vector or iterator.

```
std::vector<long long> data{0l, 1l, 2l, 3l, 4l};
std::any_of(data.begin(), data.end(), [](long long t){ return t != 0l; })
```

I read that auto is not allowed in such a way (for example):

```
std::any_of(data.begin(), data.end(), [](auto t){ return t != 0l; })
```

Is there any solution for this using **decltype**?

**UPDATE**

Apparently above line will be allowed in c++14. For c++11 the solution is

```
std::any_of(data.begin(), data.end(), [](decltype(data)::value_type t){ return t != 0l; })
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ``auto`` is not allowed in lambda in C++11. In C++14 and higher it is allowed.

Comment: it's perfectly valid since C++14

Comment: In c++11 you can use `decltype(data)::value_type`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a70a7316d0cdac0 in c++14 is perfectly valid

Comment: `[](decltype(*data.begin()) t){ return t != 0l; }`

Comment: `[](decltype(data)::value_type t){ return t != 0l; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `decltype()` in the following way:

```
  std::any_of(data.begin(), data.end(),
              [](decltype(data)::value_type t) { return t != 0l; });
```